# NEST Elastic Search - query a term with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch

I'm having hard time implementing autocomplete in elastic for DisplayName property for the text that have spaces in it, here is the setup of the field:

```
"DisplayName": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "normalizer": "caseinsensitive"
        },
        "prefix": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "startswith"
        }
    }
},
"id": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

Here is the `startwith` analyzer definition:

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "startswith": {
            "char_filter": [
                "html_strip"
            ],
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "type": "custom"
        }
    },
    "normalizer": {
        "caseinsensitive": {
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
        }
    }
},
"creation_date": "1565034410554",
"mapping": {
    "total_fields": {
        "limit": "5000"
    }
},
"number_of_shards": "5",
"provided_name": "streetsmart"
```

In my query builder here is the query that tries to grab the result:

```
_type:User AND (DisplayName.prefix:Joseph adam* OR UserPrincipalName.prefix:Joseph adam*)"
```

and the result that I get is all the names that contains `Adam` which the result should be `Joseph Adam Jr`,
Does anyone know what I should do?

[image: Result that I get]

Comment: Just put them in double quotes. `DisplayName.prefix: "Joseph adam*"`

Comment: @Delphi.Boy thanks for your answer but that doesn't work, it doesn't return anything when I put them in double quotes or single, I read somewhere that the field should be as non-analyzer but I was hoping to fix it without changing the mapping and re-indexing the data, since there are already to much data and re-indexing will take a long time.

Comment: Can u please share the definition of 'startswith' analyzer. I don't see a predefined analyzer with the name

Comment: @SahilGupta I updated and added the 'startwith' analyzer definition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of c# and .net syntax, but adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result in JSON format.

You can also use [Match phrase prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) that :

> Returns documents that contain the words of a provided text, in the
> same order as provided. The last term of the provided text is treated
> as a prefix, matching any words that begin with that term.

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name": "Adam"
}
{
    "name": "Joseph Adam Sr"
}
{
    "name": "Joseph Adam Jr"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "Joseph Adam",
            "fields": [
                "name"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64163994",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.54037446,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Joseph Adam Jr"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64163994",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.54037446,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Joseph Adam Sr"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Aren S did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: I tried that approach and I still get the same result, do I have to change anything in mapping in order `phrase_prefix` work?